# What's wrong with this Golang code for transaction signing? Invalid v,r,s error?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, ecdsa

So I'm learning more about Ethereum, and I wrote this gist in Go to start interacting with geth nodes and publishing transactions to the network. I'm getting an error that says:

`panic: invalid transaction v, r, s values`

Here's the code I wrote to send the transaction: https://gist.github.com/karysto/3c7c1ab9d3ae736e5c63a2bbe4c47ac2

Any and all help appreciated!

**Update:** It seems that the network/signer `chain id` is being mis-set somewhere. Despite the fact that I'm setting the `chain id` to `0` in the gist, the chain id for a transaction always gets set to `9223372036854775790`. My guess is the transaction is getting signed correctly but is getting signed with the incorrect chain (the one above), hence the `invalid v,r,s` error. If someone knows a way to fix this issue or finds I'm incorrect, don't hesitate to submit an answer!

**Update: March 29 2017**: I opened an [issue on Go ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/13847#issuecomment-290010116) explaining this problem.

**Geth versions tested**: `1.5.9` and `1.6.0-unstable`

Comment: what do you mean by this "Despite the fact that I'm setting the chain id in the genesis block and the gist to 0"?

Comment: My mistake, the `chain id` is only set in the gist I linked, not the genesis block. Updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this will help in any way at all but I had something I wrote just before abigen was introduced. I have tried to keep it updated (no 100% guarantee)

github.com/DaveAppleton/ether_go

Maybe it will help

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full example of how to sign a transaction and broadcast in Go (from the [Ethereum Development with Go book](https://github.com/miguelmota/ethereum-development-with-go-book)).

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/big"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
)

func main() {
    client, err := ethclient.Dial("https://rinkeby.infura.io")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    privateKey, err := crypto.HexToECDSA("fad9c8855b740a0b7ed4c221dbad0f33a83a49cad6b3fe8d5817ac83d38b6a19")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    publicKey := privateKey.Public()
    publicKeyECDSA, ok := publicKey.(*ecdsa.PublicKey)
    if !ok {
        log.Fatal("error casting public key to ECDSA")
    }

    fromAddress := crypto.PubkeyToAddress(*publicKeyECDSA)
    nonce, err := client.PendingNonceAt(context.Background(), fromAddress)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    value := big.NewInt(1000000000000000000) // in wei (1 eth)
    gasLimit := uint64(21000)                // in units
    gasPrice := big.NewInt(30000000000)      // in wei (30 gwei)

    toAddress := common.HexToAddress("0x4592d8f8d7b001e72cb26a73e4fa1806a51ac79d")
    var data []byte
    tx := types.NewTransaction(nonce, toAddress, value, gasLimit, gasPrice, data)
    signedTx, err := types.SignTx(tx, types.HomesteadSigner{}, privateKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = client.SendTransaction(context.Background(), signedTx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("tx sent: %s", signedTx.Hash().Hex())
}
```